# Container With Most Water algorithm - using recursion

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, recursion

I am doing leetcode #11 Container With Most Water

https://leetcode.com/problems/container-with-most-water/

Given n non-negative integers a1, a2, ..., an , where each represents a point at coordinate (i, ai). n vertical lines are drawn such that the two endpoints of line i is at (i, ai) and (i, 0). Find two lines, which together with x-axis forms a container, such that the container contains the most water.

Note: You may not slant the container and n is at least 2.

```
var maxArea = function (height) {
            var list = [];
            for (var index = 1; index <= height.length; index++) {
                var eachCorr = {
                    x_corr: index,
                    y_corr: height[index - 1]
                }
                list.push(eachCorr);
            }

            var mainResult = reCursion(list, list.length-1,0,1);

            console.log(list);
            console.log(mainResult);

            return mainResult;
            //last vertical line * each vertical line from index=1; 
            //x-corr*(last vertical - each vertical), y-corr*(smaller vertical line)
        };

        function reCursion(arr, index, x,y) {
            //lastX and lastY use recursion to loop
            var lastX = arr[index][x];
            var lastY = arr[index][y];
            var chosenY = 0;
            var area = 0;
            var result = [];
            var maxAreaAns = 0;
            for (var i = index - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (lastY > arr[i][1]) {
                    chosenY = arr[i][1];
                } else {
                    chosenY = lastY;
                }
                area = (lastX - arr[i][0]) * chosenY;
                console.log(`area = ${area} with i = ${i}, lastX=${lastX}, lastY=${lastY}`); 
                result.push(area);
            }
            if (index === 0) {
                maxAreaAns = Math.max(...result);
                return maxAreaAns;
            } else {
                return reCursion(arr, index - 1,0,1);
            }
        }
```

My approach is using recursion, first select the last vertical line, multiple to x-corr difference of
each vertical line before, then select the small y-corr of the vertical line when compared.

**area = (x-corr difference of last vertical line and compared vertical line) * (y-coor of small vertical line)**

Then use recursion to select the second last vertical line and so all until select the first vertical line.

Then I push all the area result into a array and find the maximum.

I want to know why this method can not execute( lastX, lastY, area variables are undefined).

Comment: ```maxArea``` seems wrong (why start at index==1), why push ```{x_corr:xx, y_corr:yy}``` when in reCursion you expect ```[xx,yy]```. In ```reCursion``` why start iterating from the end. Better ```lastX-1```? but overall, just iterate in normal order already. Last, test your algorithm yourself (write tests yourself to have quicker feedback than the platform's) and beware of spreading for Math.max which may fail if your array is too big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having analyzed your code, your

```
var lastX = arr[index][x];
var lastY = arr[index][y];
```

are both always `undefined`. Since `arr[index]` returns an object and not a list, you cannot get the values by indexing. You'll need to do

```
var lastX = arr[index].x_corr;
var lastY = arr[index].y_corr;
```

Which also goes for your

```
if (lastY > arr[i][1]) {
      chosenY = arr[i][1];
```

---

Now you might have realized that your function always logs out `-Infinity` as its result.
This is because when the condition

```
if (index === 0) {
       maxAreaAns = Math.max(...result);
       return maxAreaAns;
}
```

is met and the code inside it is executed, the `result` array is always empty (try invoking the Math.max() function without any input. It will return `-Infinity`).

This is because when the `index` variable is equal to 0, the loop

```
for (var i = index - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       if (lastY > arr[i][1]) {
       ...
}
```

will not run (as `i` starts from -1), and the `result` stays as an empty array.

---

I am guessing that what you would want to do is to either set `result` array as a global variable, or to pass it to the next `reCursion()` function.

That being said, I actually don't see the point of solving this problem using recursion.
Instead of using recursion (which obviously makes it difficult to write and understand the code), why not just use a nested loop to check the combinations?

Comment: I somehow disagree for avoiding recursion. (it may be not pertinent, but it is worth trying just to hone one's skill). Still upvoting for the detailed correction!

Comment: Oh yes, I absolutely agree with you. It is a very good practice.